# Is this possible for others to implements a `fake` Java object within the src?

Tags: java, security

I got a Java programme that read a java Serial object, if it is received, the programme will run some business logic. Assume that I don't have the Java programme source code, I also don't have any documents on how the Serial object implements. Is this possible to made a `fake` client that can let the programme execute?

Thanks.

Comment: Look into using a mocking framework such as EasyMock or Mockito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Java Serialisation.

In theory you should be able to look at the serial stream and see what classes and fields are expected. You could then construct a class just in time (if using `ObjectInputStream` to parse the stream, you might need to restart reading the stream each time (not sure)). Any data written after `defaultWriteObject`/`putFields` in custom `writeObject` methods wouldn't be reliably interpretable.

In practice, people (including authors of the Java library) are sometimes a bit naughty and miss out the `defaultWriteObject`/`putFields`. This means that the stream is not actually in the correct format. It's probably a bit late to fix that now due to backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The fake client would have to know the name of the expected class, which is discoverable from the exception message when it isn't found; its serialVersionUID ditto; and its serializable fields, which are *not* discoverable ditto. In theory it is possible to discover that from the serialized stream, but given that any class can have its own writeObject() or writeExternalizable() method it can get arbitrarily complex arbitrarily quickly.

So I wouldn't lose too much sleep over this as a casual risk.

You could also sign the JAR and seal the package concerned, which would eliminate that specific risk.

OTOH if you have a genuine neeed for application security you are looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely follow your thinking.

You can't inject new code into an application by getting it to deserialize objects.  In order for an object to be successfully deserialized by / in a program, that program has to have the classes for the objects on the classpath.  If it doesn't, deserialization will fail.

On the other hand, if you somehow knew that the program already used a particular class with a particular security flaw AND you could trick it into deserializing an instance of that class in such a way that the flaw could be exploited, then there would be a concern.  (And I vaguely recall that this approach has been used with certain vulnerable classes, though I can't recall any details.)

---

The bottom line is that a security conscious application should not attempt to deserialize objects that might come from untrusted sources, or that might have been modified in transit.